# The minimum number of launch images for a Universal App

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a universal app which supports both orientations and all resolutions, so there are a bunch of possible splash images (iphone & ipad, portrait & landscape (left/right), retina & std display). But there is no sense to show anything except the background image as a splash image for my app. And the background is just a simple repeated pattern, so ideally I just specify a little 10x10 pixels image and tile the screen with it.

But as I understand it's not possible, and I need to provide a bunch of pre-rendered full-screen images. So I wonder what is the minimum number of images that is required for a Universal app? Will just one Default.png be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum number you can provide is **zero**. If your app is quick to launch, you don't need to supply one. If your app is slow to launch, make it faster by putting heavyweight stuff on a background thread and get the UI (or a plain view with your tiled pattern) on screen as fast as possible.

Comment: Note this is not true currently. Apple now requires all apps to have launch images.

Comment: @sergio yeah, things have moved on in the 3+ years since this was posted!

Answer (score 3):

In your case i would place 4 Default png's.

And yes. You need to pre-fill your 10x10 tiles in a (or multiple) big default.png files.

two for iPad (iPad / iPad Retina) and two for iPhone (iPhone / iPhone retina).

You need to set the base name in your app plist.
Look for `Launch image (iPad)` then enter there `DefaultiPad` (or something like this). Then you should place a DefaultiPad.png and a DefaultiPad@2x.png within your project resources.

Do the same for iPhone.
Look after `Launch image (iPhone)` in your app plist and do the same with a different base name.

**Update 1:**
You can also add Default.pngs for each device orientation.
Easiest way is to go with `[Basename]-Landscapen.png` and `[Basename]-Portrait.png`.
So in the case above you can place your files with the filename `DefaultiPad-Landscape.png` and `DefaultiPad-Portrait.png`

But this will also increase your binary filesize which – maybe for your 10x10 tile case - will not be worth doing so.

Comment: depending on how your background looks, you maybe want to specify different launch images for each rotation for the iPad. 

(Default-Portrait.png and Default-Landscape.png)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are asking for the minimum:

> Every app must provide at least one launch image. This image is typically in a file named Default.png that displays your app’s initial screen in a portrait orientation. However, you can also provide other launch images to be used under different launch conditions.

Source: [App Launch (Default) Images](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12)

However, I also would suggest to use at least 4 (iPad + iPhone each in normal and @2x).

Comment: Interesting. I have apps on the store with no launch images, contrary to the documentation above.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it by just providing a small image and having it tile, you have to provide an actual, pre-made image for everything you want to support. In your case:

- 4 images for iPad (Landscape, Portrait, Landscape 2x, Portrait 2x)
- 2 images for iPhone (Portrait, Portrait 2x)

Left and right are the same image, unless you do something different with those orientations. Upside-down is the same too.

If you think that's a lot, wait until you see how many icons you need.

More info is at [App Launch (Default) Images](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12)

Comment: look at your linked source, iPhone doesn't support landscape launch images.